# Export oracle database to another server

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, export, dbmigrate

How can i migrate oracle database from one server to another along with data?

Database is on Window server and i need to copy it to another window server. Nothing complex :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option from an administrative perspective would be to do a full export and import.  The Data Pump versions of the export and import utilities will be more efficient than the classic version.  The dump file that is generated can be imported into a later version of Oracle on any platform.

The downside of using export and import, however, is that it takes a while.  You have to read all the data out of the database to the file system and write it all back into the new database.  If you don't want to lose data, that means a potentially hefty downtime.

If you don't have the downtime window to do a full export and import, you could restore your last backup to the new machine if you want to run exactly the same version of Oracle on the same operating system.  You can also use [cross-platform transportable tablespaces](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/tspaces.htm#sthref1288).

Answer (score 0):

[dbmantain](http://www.dbmaintain.org/overview.html), [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) strike to my mind. Also follow this SO posts

[What kind of database refactoring tools are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27663/what-kind-of-database-refactoring-tools-are-there)

[Database Migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767846/database-migration)

Answer (score 0):

There's several aspects to consider.

Do the source and destination machines share the same [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). If they are both x86 based, then the answer would be yes.

Do they share the same OS ?

Do they share storage ?

Are they on the same network ?

Does the destination machine already have Oracle installed ?

Is it the same version/release of Oracle ?

Is it the same Edition of Oracle ?

What is the data volume ? What downtime are you allowed ?

In the easiest scenario (same OS/endianess/shared storage/Oracle release/Oracle edition) then you should be able to simply shut down the instance on the old machine and start up one on the new machine

In the most complex (different endianess/no shared storage or network/different Oracle release and edition) then an import/export is probably the only practical solution.